# i cant copy paste the rig that i downloaded from sketchfab

Tags: rendering, mesh, rigging

hey everyone sorry for asking many questions , i just wanna learn from small mistakes in blender from you guys so thanks all for the help , i downloaded this eagle with animation the problem im facing right now i downloaded it with fbx but without texture it worked fine , but with gltf with texture but not animated , so i went to rig body on the fbx object tried to paste it to gltf it worked but of course the animation is broken , i can provide the file if you guys dont get what i mean , or is there a fix for that , thank you for the reply here is a picture[image]